# case classes return Product instead of actual type

Tags: scala, case-class

I have a trait and a few case classes extending this trait.

```
sealed trait Bird
case class Eagle(age: Int) extends Bird
case class Sparrow(price: Double) extends Bird
```

If I do a anything that I would expect to return the Trait as a type, like

```
val result = "test" match {
  case s:String if s startsWith "t" => Eagle(5)
  case _ => Sparrow(2)
}
```

I get instead this `Product` type.

```
> result: Product with Serializable with Bird = Eagle(5)
```

I understand `Product` is something that all case classes extend. But I don't what to deal with `Product`, how can I get `Bird` or even `Eagle` back instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just ignore the aspects you don't care about. `result` *is* a `Bird`, so use it as one. That it is also a `Product` and a `Serializable` is not relevant (unless you want/need it to be). You can make it explicit by specifying its expected type:

```
val result: Bird = "test" match {
  case s:String if s startsWith "t" => Eagle(5)
  case _ => Sparrow(2)
}
```

Gives:

```
result: Bird = Eagle(5)
```

Or, you can assign it to another variable of type `Bird`, or simply expect it to be a `Bird` and charge ahead, calling methods defined on the `Bird` trait, passing it as an argument to a function taking a parameter of type `Bird`, etc.